# Why doesn't this work: ~$ echo "trythis" | sh ./script.sh

Tags: command-line, scripts, pipe

I'm trying to feed the string `trythis` into the script I made that creates a directory using what is written after it. 
For example this works:

```
~$ sh ./script trythis
```

But using the pipe does not. 
I am rather new to scripting so still getting the hang of various concepts.

Comment: Why did you expect it to work?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980090/how-to-read-from-a-file-or-stdin-in-bash)

Comment: I was going to add to my answer whole lot of extra information about how things work  behind the scenes, but considering you're somewhat new to scripting I've put that aside for now. Too much information can be overwhelming. Please let me know if you do what extra clarifications on any of the things in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Because pipe and positional parameters are different things

Pipes connect stdin stream of right most command in pipeline to the stdout of left most command. The effect is such as if one command becomes keyboard-like input to the other.

By contrast positional parameters as in

```
myscript.sh trythis
```

create an array of values, where myscript and trythis are items in that array, and there is no connection to stdin stream at all

What you should do in such cases is use `xargs`

```
echo trythis | xargs myscript
```

The `xargs` command will run the `myscript` command with `trythis` added to the front as if done manually.

In other words, exactly because  `sh ./script trythis`  expects `trythis` to be there in positional parameter list you don't see `echo trythis | sh ./myscript` working. If you did `echo try this | sh ./myscript trythis` it would work, because now you have positional parameter list, and echo technically becomes redundant.

Of course, it is the application's own decision on what to do with either stdin or positional parameters. Commands such as `echo` don't care about stdin but only about positional parameters, whereas `cat` would care about both. If you were to build a script in such way that reads stdin AND accepts positional parameters, then it could also work, for instance `grep` and `tail` do that. And exactly in those cases where we want to dynamically create positional parameters or the application ignores stdin - there is the right place to use `xargs`.